# Double click on list box contents to open it in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a list box that contains some existed file names. I have a push button. User select the file needed and after that click on push button to open it. Is any way to open a file  when user double click on the file name of the file in list box?

Comment: Please show some code on what you've done so far.  That way we can help you further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Callback of the uicontrol listbox, along with the [SelectionType](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-SelectionType) property of the figure object.
You can find an example in MATLAB documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/interactive-list-box-in-a-guide-gui.html#f6-7913).

Comment: Your first link was broken (so I've removed it), and you should write the content of the second link's page in your answer to avoid this answer being completely useless if it breaks too. Answers should always aim to be self contained for this reason!